# Update Multiple SSRS Reports in bulk

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to make identical changes to hundreds of reports, and I was hoping to do this via SQL instead of each indvidual report and it's query. I can extract the report query via xml and generate my list of reports, their location, and the query being used. But what I cannot figure out is how to update the report query and then get that updated back into the Catalog? database so that the report itself reflects the changes when executed? I have never seen where this is possible, but maybe someone on here has tried to do this or knows that it's flat out not possible.

I could use SSIS and do this, but I would prefer not to download all the RDLs and then update, and then redeploy/upload the reports. Was hoping to update in place the reports/RDLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to download the RDLs, they should already be in your source control system, and ideally collected and grouped into project(s). If so, you are in luck - you can use the global search/replace capabilities of Visual Studio (BIDS) or Notepad++ to make your change.

If your change was to the structure of the report then you could simply write a quick nasty console app to load the RDL and manipulate the XML structure. But things like the report query are held as free-form text in a node, making it harder to apply mass updates in a reliable way.

You could look to refactor the report queries into stored procedures and/or functions, this will make future updates a bit easier. In any case if you change the report RDLs you've got no option but to republish the modified ones - there's no such thing as an in-place change on the server (having your queries as stored procedures would have avoided this issue).

Comment: Slugster, thanks for the comments and confirmation. Unfortunately the reports are created by several different people in the business, and I walked into this mess a few months back. I completely agree about using stored procedures and it's what I typically recommend, when I can control this. :-(